# Is there a way to shutdown the computer when Dropbox finishes synching?

Tags: windows-7, automation, shutdown, dropbox

We are using Dropbox and sometimes put large files in it. And our connection is not fast enough. So we want the computer to shutdown when Dropbox finishes its work. Is there a way to do this? In Dropbox or some generic solution...

OS:Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "Shutdown Timer" a donationware utility that I think does exactly what you want:

http://sinvise.net/home/projects/software/shutdown-timer

Answer (score 2):

Found this: http://emtunc.org/blog/03/2011/dropbox-automatically-standby-pc-after-sync/

It's based on a python script that check the sync status of a folder http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Python_Script_To_Get_File_Or_Folder_Status_In_Windows

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request filed at [Votebox](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/61/shutdown-after-sync) for this and You could also try [Swith Off, Auto Shutdown and others](http://alternativeto.net/software/auto-shutdown/) to schedule a shutdown.